# Poisson Binomial Distribution - confidence intervals

Tags: mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval, references, inference, poisson-binomial-distribution

I'm working on a project which involves multiple trials for which the probability of success is not the same across trials.  Given the unequal probabilities per trial, I'm using the Poisson Binomial distribution.

I can easily model the probability of a given number of successes across all trials using the `R` package [`poisbinom`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/poisbinom/index.html).  Looking at the problem the other way around, I would also like to provide confidence intervals on the probability of successes given an observed number of successes.

For the Binomial Distribution, I know this can be done using a normal approximation when $p>0.1$ and $n>15$, but I cannot find a reference for computing CIs for the Poisson Binomial Distribution.  This is obviously complicated by the fact that each trial has a different probability of success

Any references to using a normal approximation or other methods is appreciated.

EDIT:

I've been doing some simulations to see if a normal approximation (Wald Method) would work, and generally I see the same results I would expect to see as with a Binomial Distribution.  The empirical variability I see from the simulation is certainly non-normal, but normal approximation does a reasonably good job with 2 decimal points - 0.## +/- 0.## when the sample size is large.

[From some background reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Confidence_intervals), the same deviation from normal is seen for the Binomial Distribution and various approximation methods are proposed.  The Wald Method is simple but biased.

From what I've seen from simulations, I think similar CI methods as those used for a Binomial Distribution would work.

UPDATE:

I've tried multiple types of CI calculation that are applicable to the Binomial Distribution, or more specifically, the Binomial Proportion - Wald, Agresti-Coull, Wilson. [see here for descriptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval)  From my simulations, Wald performs best across the broadest range of values.  The others are generally more often recommended, but I think that is primarily for proportions that are very small (< 0.01) or very large (> 0.99).

I feel I've answered my own question here, but I appreciate any feedback.

Comment: If you only have 1 sequence of the n trials & only know the success parameters are unequal without knowing a given relationship, I don't see how you can estimate the $p_i$s much less get confidence intervals. It seems that the most you can say is that for the $p_i$s that have a failure are <1.

Comment: See also:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/455865/poisson-binomial-distribution-hypothesis-test/458625#458625

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear what you really want. The Poisson-Binomial distribution on $n$ trials have $n$ probability parameters $p_1, \dotsc, p_n$ so you cannot reasonably expect a confidence interval for each of them! So, for this question to be answerable, you need to specify some function of the $p_i$'s that you are interested in. So, what is your real inferential goal? Let's say your Poisson-Binomial random variable is $X=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ where the $X_i$'s are independent Bernoulli with probability $p_i$. Maybe your interest is in

1. $\DeclareMathOperator{\P}{\mathbb{P}}   \bar{p}=\frac1{n} \sum p_i$
2. The fraction of the $p_i$'s above 0.7?
3. The variance of the $p_i$'s?
4. $\P(X \ge 0.78 n)$?

or some other functional? As soon as you specify your [*focus parameter*](https://www.mn.uio.no/math/english/research/projects/focustat/summary-report-(january-2019)/focustat_sluttrapport.pdf), or otherwise your inferential goal, we can probably propose some confidence interval.

Your question also could benefit from some context. The Poisson-Binomial distribution is so general, more of a modeling framework, so context could give important hints to modeling. Some papers leading to ideas: [Probability of forest fires](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/users/brill/Papers/WF02061.pdf),   [Species Distribution Models](http://portal.uni-freiburg.de/biometrie/mitarbeiter/dormann/calabrese2013globalecolbiogeogr.pdf),   [Species Distribution models 2](https://besjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/2041-210X.12332),   [simulation-based CI (JSTOR)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/24591436?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents).